# How can I verify that the remapped models via imported mappings are valid in OpenAPI Generator result?

Tags: openapi-generator

I am using `OpenAPI Generator` via the `Gradle` plugin to generate an API client from a `yaml` spec file. By using the `importMappings` in combination with `.openapi-generator-ignore` file I am able to remap some of the models to existing classes in my codebase.

Question: on API client generation script invocation, is there any way to enable remap verification to check if the external models conform to the ones described in the spec file? In the logs obtained with the `debug` and `verbose` flags I see only that the spec models that I expect to not be generated are indicated as `[INFO] [...] Ignore <file path> (Ignored by rule in ignore file)`.